# DataGrid binding issues

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, infragistics

Has it ever happened to you that a datagrid bound to another element's selecteditems collection, doesn't update the first time an item of the second element is chosen? After the first attempt everything works fine. It is necessary to mention that I've set the AutoGenerateColumns to false, and define the columns myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently a [thread](http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/41345/230350.aspx#230350) for this issue the Infragistics forums. This seems to be e bug with the grid. You can find a workaround in the thread.